# Difficulties with the PGF of X+Y with Y~Poisson(1) and X~Poisson(Y)

Tags: random-variable, expected-value, poisson-distribution, conditional-expectation, probability-generating-fn

> The pair of random variables $(X, Y )$ is distributed as follows. $Y$ has probability mass function $\text{Poisson}(1).$ Given $Y , X$ has probability mass function $\text{Poisson}(Y ).$ Show that the probability generation function of $ X + Y $ equals:
> $$G_{X+Y}(s)=\exp[se^{s-1}-1]$$

I tried to do the following:
$$G_{X+Y}(s)=\mathbb{E}(s^{X+Y})=\mathbb{E}(\mathbb{E}(s^{X+Y}|Y))=\mathbb{E}(s^Y\mathbb{E}(s^X|Y))$$

I am stuck with the $\mathbb{E}(s^X|Y)$ part. By definition we know :
$\mathbb{E}(X|Y))=\sum_{1}^{\infty}x\mathbb{P}(X=x|Y)$, but how do we apply and determine it for $s^X$?

Comment: I didn't downvote. But isn't it given that $X\sim\textrm{Poi}(Y) $?

Comment: @User1865345 Yes it is given

Comment: Do you know the definition of $\mathbb{E}(f(X)|Y)$?

Comment: @jbowman The definition is : $\mathbb{E}(f(X)|Y)=\sum_{x\in Im X}f(x)\mathbb{P}(f(X)=f(x)|Y)=\sum_{x\in Im X}f(x)p_{X|Y}(X=x|Y)$. I think I solved it can you check my answer below

Answer (score 6):

The pgf of a Poisson random variable with parameter $\lambda$ is $G(s)=e^{\lambda(s-1)}$. Hence
\begin{align}
G_{X+Y}(s)&=E(s^{X+Y}) &&\text{(by definition of the pgf)} 
\\&=E(E(s^{X+Y}|Y)) &&\text{(law of total expectation)}
\\&=E(s^YE(s^X|Y))
\\&=E(s^YG_{X|Y}(s)) &&\text{(by definition of the pgf)}
\\&=E(s^Ye^{Y(s-1)}) &&\text{(since $X|Y\sim\operatorname{Poisson}(Y)$)}
\\&=E((se^{s-1})^Y)
\\&=G_Y(se^{s-1}) &&\text{(by definition of the pgf)}
\\&=e^{se^{s-1}-1}. &&\text{(since $Y\sim\operatorname{Poisson}(1)$)}
\end{align}

Comment: For a moment, I thought you switched X and Y. But now it is correct. +1. The info was given and OP couldn't drive through (that's why those comments above).